# Zooming into Background Nodes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I was having an issue with creating a zoomable background Node in SpriteKit using an image.  I wanted to use an image larger than my view in order to be able to eventually pan around and zoom about. However, when I add the node to the scene it does not appear.  The image is quite large (6300 x 3000) and simply will not load. I've tried centering it and it just appears as black.  When I add a node that is the size of the view, it does display.  The code is is follows:

```
let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Space_BG_1b")


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {



    background.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2)
    background.zPosition = 0
    addChild(background)
}
```

Comment: @68cherries It's not a set background, I'm just adding an image node into the scene to be set as a background. The problem is that this node is not being loaded with it's image.

Comment: @68cherries the code is the one found in the original post.

Comment: the image may be bigger than spritekit allows